# "10 reps of every required healthy exercise every hour for 10 hours" vs. "100 reps of every required healthy exercise every day"

Tags: hypertrophy, resting-metabolic-rate

"10 reps of every required healthy exercise every hour for 10 hours" vs. "100 reps of every required healthy exercise every day" - both performed by two different men for 1 year. Initially, both individuals' BMI was 16, indicating they were underweight and weak. They followed their respective approaches every single day, taking rest on Sundays. After one year, which approach do you think will result in a better physique?

Answer (score 1):

It’s impossible to say. Different individuals respond differently to different training, you haven’t told us anything about their diets, and we don’t know what “every required healthy exercise” is. There’s no way to answer this question, and if there was, it would be useless since no one lives their lives in such a way to make either program feasible.

Comment: They both take healthy diet. I could say they do push ups. But then, I was afraid you would say it's not okay to do only push ups. That's why I said a set of required healthy exercise. I know no one lives in such a way. That's why I asked.

Comment: The question is theoretical. So I'm not expecting the answer to be 100% true. Just like Physicists make theories but these theories are not 100% false. Because they were based on some assumptions and facts. Similarly, I'm expecting the answer in a similar way.

Comment: Plus, people like the second person in question exist in real life. They do 100 reps of X exercise every single day except one day for rest.

Comment: Both of these scenarios boil down to 100 reps per day.  The only real difference here is that the second is technically more flexible, they could do it exactly the same way as the first person.  I don't know if there's much literature at all about how spreading out exercises within a single day affect hypertrophy, but at a guess I'd say both approaches are equivalent.